# "Moitié" or "demi" décaféiné (coffee)?

Tags: vocabulaire, adverbes, alimentation, préfixes

I was recently in Québec, Canada. I wanted to order a half decaf coffee (that is, a coffee that is 50% decaf and 50% regular).

"Un café, demi-décaffiné" confused people.

Why? It worked when I asked for it "moitié decaf", but I was under the impression that moitié meant "a half of" something, not "made up of one half of", which is what I thought demi meant. I obviously mixed something up somewhere but I'm not sure where and, strangely, looking on websites about this distinction is not clarifying...

Comment: Thanks! That at least clarifies the phrase, but what's the difference then? Why was demi-decaf wrong?

Comment: *demi-décaffiné* sounds like a decaffeination process that only removed half the caffeine, like for [*lait demi-écrémé*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lait_demi-%C3%A9cr%C3%A9m%C3%A9) (semi-skimmed milk). That's a bit confusing because that's not what you want.

Comment: @con-gras-tue-les-chiens it's not super uncommon where I went. The point of sale terminal has a button for it...

Comment: @MichaelStachowsky Was there a label printed on that button?

Comment: Yes but it comes up as "1/2 decaf" which I guess works no matter which language it is :-P

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It must be possible to use "à demi décaféiné" as the terms "moitié" and "à demi" are synonyms.

> (TLFi) **moitié** :  Emploi adv. À demi.
>
> - Ils vous laissent sur la place moitié sans connaissance par la strangulation.  (Dict. compl. arg. Myst. Paris, 1844, p.64)
> - Une variété d'œillets laquelle n'était pas moitié aussi belle, (...) aussi grande quant aux dimensions des fleurs que celles qu'ils avaient obtenues depuis longtemps chez la princesse.  (PROUST, Guermantes 2, 1921, p.437)

> (TLFi) **à demi** : Loc. adv. Exprime qu'un procès n'est réalisé qu'incomplètement, partiellement. Synon. à moitié, presque; anton. tout à fait, complètement, totalement, etc.

As "demi" is an adjective, it's a word that can't be used to modify an adjective and "à demi" is the term to use; for instance, "un verre demi plein" is not correct but  "un verre à demi  plein" is.

You can also say "mi-décaféiné";

> (TLFi) **Mi- + adj.** (ou part. passé adj.) [Les mots constr. sont des adj.; ils définissent un état intermédiaire entre deux réalités dont l'une est implicite. Mi- y a la même valeur que les loc. adv. à demi, à moitié] V. mi-clos, mi-lourd, […]

It should be possible to use any of the four following forms, although in European French you can't use the four in all cases;

**moitié décaféiné, à moitié décaféiné, à demi décafféiné, mi-décafféiné**

For instance you can say "moitié  convaincu", "à moitié convaincu", "à demi convaincu" but not "mi-convaincu", except when there is a repetition with another adjective;

Finaud la regardait d'un œil mi-interrogateur, mi-narquois, […] ([ref](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/mi-))

My guess is that people are confused more by the fact that "moitié" is the traditional term than by the fact that "demi" is not correct ; they might be confused as well by "à demi".

Comment: @Fólkvangr Le plan sémantique est couvert dans la définition de « moitié », par laquelle on passe à « à demi », cela signifiant « un procès partiellement achevé » et non comme serait induit à le croire l'OP « constitué d'une moitié de qqc ». Cela doit être vrai puisque le mot moitié vient de « half  decafeinated », ce qui signifie qu'un  procédé de décaféination est effectué à 50 %. Les citations aident peut être à comprendre que, comme en anglais, moitié ne signifie pas nécessairement « 50 % ». Le fait que « demi » ne soit pas compris n'est pas compréhensible, sur aucun plan.

Comment: @suiiurisesse Il me semblait que ces cafés n'était pas le mélange de deux produits mais un seul produit initialement obtenu par un procédé de décaféination, comme [celui-ci](https://www.amazon.ca/Maxwell-House-Half-Caff-torr%C3%A9faction/dp/B01759WFV0).

Comment: @suiiurisesse Je crois ça maintenant, c'est un mélange.

Answer (score 17):

Not sure about Québec, but I I don't thing this kind of drink is usual in France. (Disclaimer, I don't drink coffee, whether caffeinated or not).

You generally order either ***un café*** or ***un déca***.

If you want it to be mixed on site, you might ask for:

- *un mélange **moitié-moitié**<sup>1</sup> **café déca***;
- *un café **mi-normal**<sup>2</sup> [,] **mi-déca***; (built like *[mi-figue mi-raisin](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/mi-figue_mi-raisin)* or *[mi-bière, mi-vin](https://www.lapresse.ca/vins/bieres/biere-de-la-semaine/201501/04/01-4832389-myrcene-de-glace-mi-biere-mi-vin.php)*).
- *un café **moitié normal, moitié déca***.

*Demi-décaféiné* sounds odd because *demi* usually means half the regular size (*une demi-bouteille de vin = 37.5 cl, un demi = une demi-pinte de bière = 25 cl*) so ***un demi-déca*** might be understood as an half-filled cup of decaffeinated coffee. It would be even more confusing if you ask for a ***double café demi-décaféiné*** ;-) However, as a counter-example there is the well known expression ***lait demi-écrémé*** (suggested by Teleporting Goat in a comment) that pose no problem and might be considered technically similar to a mixture of ***lait entier*** and ***lait écrémé***.

For a coffee naturally low in caffeine or for a coffee that has been partially decaffeinated, an idiomatic expression might be *un café **semi-décaféiné***.

There are a few occurrences of **semi-caféiné** but this seems odd. That would mean a decaffeinated coffee to which some caffeine has been subsequently added.

<sup>1</sup> <sub>[Dictionnaire de l'Académie](https://www.dictionnaire-academie.fr/article/A9M2522-A) :

Fam. *Moitié-moitié*, en deux parts égales. *Partager les bénéfices moitié-moitié. Moitié-moitié*, se dit aussi en réponse à une question pour signifier « plus ou moins, en partie seulement ».</sub>

<sup>2</sup> <sub>*mi-normal* meaning *mi-café-normal*</sub>

Comment: Never heard of such a drink i nBelgium neither. I'm also NOT a coffee drinker myself though.

Answer (score 7):

J'ai posé la question à une barista de mon café du coin (pas une chaîne) au Québec (sud-ouest). On m'a dit qu'on pouvait le préparer, normalement le client explique ce qu'il veut mais elle pense qu'on dit *moitié-moitié* (identique aux solutions d'une [autre réponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/37337)). Il va sans dire que *moitié-moitié* contient une part de non-dit, par ellipse, et nécessite de spécifier *déca(f)(éiné)* à quelque part ou une connaissance préalable du désir du client suite à des visites répétées...

Autrement dans un commentaire on m'a mentionné un café instantané « mi-caféiné » et la liste des [ingrédients](http://www.kraftcanada.com/produits/00066188136306) révèle qu'il s'agit d'un mélange de café (caféiné) et de café décaféiné ; il en va de même pour un café en capsule d'une marque bien connue qu'on a nommé [*Half Caffeinato*](https://www.nespresso.com/ca/fr/order/capsules/vertuo/half-caffeinato-vertuo-coffee-capsule) où la description révèle un « mariage d’Arabicas caféinés et décaféinés » alors qu'un [compétiteur](https://www.keurig.ca/fr/boissons/cafe/mi-cafeine-recyclable/p/half-caff-coffee-gmc-recyclable-k-cup-pods) emploie le terme « mi-caféiné » mais sans expliquer exactement de quoi il s'agirait. Je trouve personnellement que l'emploi de [*mi-*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/mi-) pour l'« état intermédiaire entre deux réalités dont l'une est implicite » porte à confusion ; de toutes façons ce serait avec la même valeur que les locutions adverbiales *à demi, à moitié* (TLFi) ; le problème à mon avis c'est qu'un café décaféiné auquel on ajoute un café caféiné devient un café caféiné tout simplement, il n'y a pas d'état intermédiaire, même s'il y avait une (plus) faible teneur en caféine. On préfère de loin les solutions avec *moitié/moitié* retenues dans la réponse mentionnée.

Answer (score 1):

Briefly, as indicated in my dictionary, "demi" means "half" whereas "semi-" means incomplete or imperfect. Both terms have a close meaning, it *may* refer to the idea of proportion (percentage). Moreover, the dictionary says that "semi" comes from "à demi". The word "semi" is less specific concerning the notion of proportion.

I would have said "un café semi-décaféiné" or "un décaféiné" considering only the expression, leaving aside the coffee (to order a coffee).

Comment: Pourquoi dis-tu qu'« un décaféiné » convient si il y a clairement de la caféine vu que c'est un mélange ? Si tu demandes ça au café, tu n'auras pas ce dont parles la personne qui pose la question (_that is, a coffee that is 50% decaf and 50% regular_)...

Comment: I don't get the "discordant" point. Aren't all mixtures made of two (or more) components by definition?

Comment: *Un café mi-normal* means nothing indeed, or more precisely is a truncated expression just like would be *une créature mi-homme*.

Comment: Le garçon de café n'étant probablement pas un grammairien, il ne verra pas d'objection à **un mélange moitié moitié café déca** qui, d'une part, est parfaitement compréhensible et d'autre part, correspond à la boisson souhaitée. Un exemple d'usage: [Préparer un mélange moitié moitié sucre en poudre/sel fin, dans une assiette creuse.](http://forum.cancoillotte.net/viewtopic.php?t=8757) En revanche, si on lui demande **un décaféiné**, on n'aura pas le breuvage attendu...

Comment: « *[Décriable](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=d%C3%A9criable&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1600&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=)* » est discutable, en particulier de la part de quelqu'un si attaché aux normes...

Comment: L'emploi adjectival de l'adverbe est une sujet intéressant, digne d'une question sans doute... _à peu près une douzaine, il a très peur, un passé déjà très loin_ etc. _Moitié-moitié_ aussi : « Ce collège est géré MOITIÉ-MOITIÉ par la municipalité et par le chapitre des chanoines de Saint-Bernard » (Le Roy Ladurie). Peut-être que c'est une analogie avec _presque_ qui permettrait de relier le deuxième aux emplois particuliers de l'adverbe. Intéressant...